# Use spreadsheet function in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm currently working on a work/time log in a Google Spreadsheet. I'm doing some calculations on how much time I've spent working.

I have a cell containing the number of worked hours represented in a "Time value" number.

E.g. 13:30 hours is represented as `0.559`. And I want to represent it as `13,5`.

In the cell's function I can do `HOUR(0.559)` to get the hours. But I want to use my custom function (due to otherwise very long expressions in the cell), like `HoursToDecimal(0.559)`

Now, I cannot use the `HOUR()` function in my function because it says its not defined? How can I use it?

```
function HoursToDecimal(hours_in)
{
  return (INT(hours_in)*24+HOUR(hours_in)+MINUTE(hours_in)/60);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand how your custom function is supposed to work. GApps stores date/time values as days and fractions of days. If you put a time, such as 13:30, in a cell, google will display it as a time, but will internally convert it to a fraction of a day ( 13.5 / 24 = 0.5625 )

To convert this to hours, just multiply by 24:

```
hoursworked = timeworked * 24;
```

Round and/or truncate to your liking.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up for me. It was simple. I didnt understand how GApps was storing time values.